# Get control of an existing open window using Teststake White

Tags: ui-automation, white-framework

For some reason, TestStake.White is not able to open an old windows application (which i can successfully run(win 7) by doubliclicking on the exe). I want to use an existing window to perform some action using White. I have no idea as to how to take control of an already opened window using White.

I tried to open the exe using batch command, but I still couldn't get any success. It shows me a yellow screen(app background) with no mouse control. Hence I want to launch the app manually and perform some automation actions on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the text in the title bar of the window:

```
using TestStack.White;

public static class Demo
{
   public static Window GetWindow(string windowTitle)
   {
      var window = Desktop.Instance.Windows().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == windowTitle);
   }
}
```